# What items can I get via Hunters for Hire?

Tags: monster-hunter-3-ultimate

[Hunters for Hire](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113455/what-is-hunters-for-hire) allows me to send NPCs out on a hunt while I do other things.  It's a great way to get some extra monster parts, but can I get the same parts via Hunters for Hire that I could get if I did the hunt myself?

For example, can I get a Brachydios Gem via Hunters for Hire?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure if you can get rare items from Hunters for Hire; I've only gotten common items, like Shards and Cortexes.  I can't find the acquisition rate for these hunts, but the one thing the various forums agree on is that you can't acquire rare items from sending out Hunters.

That said, there are some specific items you can *only* get from Hunters for Hire.  These are the Blossom Cricket for Low Rank, Butterfly Beetle for High Rank, and Maiden Butterfly for G Rank.

These items, in turn, are used for armor sets and some special weaponry.  There's no specific one for Low Rank, but the [Aelucanth](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/MH3U:ArmorBladeHR#Aelucanth_Armor) (for male) and [Rhopessa](http://monsterhunter.wikia.com/wiki/Rhopessa_Armor_%28Blade%29) (for female) armor sets use both the Low Rank and High Rank Hunter for Hire-only items.  The female armor, especially, looks striking due to the wings on your back.